# django url reverse hiding keyword arguments

Tags: python, django, django-views

Consider a request coming from this url `/messages/compose/(?P<recipients>[\+\.\w]+)/` where recipients is usernames separated by `+` sign. After success (message to recipients successfully sent) i am doing:

```
#success_url = 'message_send_success'
recipients = '+'.join([obj.username for obj in recipients]) #converting them back to original string
reverse(success_url, kwargs={'recipients': recipients})
```

This is the url to whom it match:

```
url(r'^/messages/success/(?P<recipients>[\+\.\w]+)$', 'site.views.message_send_success', name='message_send_success')
```

But it will show all recipients in the url, is there any away i can hide those recipients string to be displayed in url and can access it in request??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not if you're using a redirect. Django has a ["shared-nothing" architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture), which means that between one request and the next no user state persists on the server. For this reason, Django can't (automatically) "remember" what your recipients were before the redirect, so it can access them in the next HTTP request.

What are your reasons for wanting to hide them? Is there sensitive information you can't send back to the client, or something like that? One option to avoid that is to simply repeat the information the client sent (i.e. the original `recipients` parameter) and have the `success` view redo the operations that `compose` did on them.

Comment: One reason is that it looks messy in url, if user sent message to 20 users at same time then all 20 usernames will be displayed in url. And it is also un-secure as usernames in url goes public.

Comment: In that case, you should not send them to the client, encoded or not. One option I already said, repeat the original `recipients` parameter, another would be using a temporary table to store the results of `compose`. IMHO the former is better, I don't think simplifying the url is worth the extra effort to store state in the server in this case. But it's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use base64 library:

```
>>> base64.b64encode("what is that?")
'd2hhdCBpcyB0aGF0Pw=='
>>> base64.b64decode("d2hhdCBpcyB0aGF0Pw==")
'what is that?'
```

Note: if you want to have more safety urls, you should do some translations on that string (otherwise other user that know base (en)coding will easily decode your value.